# Undesirable shadow on window view during a flip

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm using a custom flip transition during a push transition.
I use this code and the flip is good:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MyViewController* myViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                                 @"MyViewController"];


[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

The problem is during the transition. I have a kind of shadow on all the window view. I can change the color but the shadow stays. An example with a red background ([UIColor RedColor]):

[image: Shadow during flip]

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Max have you every solved this problem?

Comment: @Arpit If I remember well, the cause was a shadow generated by ViewDeckController. So I removed it.